# Swift Combine: send completion after send value

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm working on caching for my network module. My module will return an `AnyCancallable` back to the caller for each request. If cached data is not available, I use `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher`, it works fine with 2 events: data received and completion. If cached data is available, I will use a  `CurrentValueSubject` to create the AnyCancallable to return. I send both of the 2 events on this subject, but on the caller side, it only gets notified on the completion, no data.

```
cacheSubject.send(cachedData.data)
cacheSubject.send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>.finished)
```

Removing the completion send and now it can receive data, but no completion notification.

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the full file in case you guys need it:

```
public class SSNetworkManager {
    public static let shared = SSNetworkManager()
    
    private var cache: [String: CachedData] = [:]
    private let cacheSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Data, Error>(Data())
    
    @discardableResult public func makeServiceCall<D: Decodable>(forRequest request: SSNetworkRequest<D>, onMainThread: Bool = true) -> AnyPublisher<D, Error>? {
        guard let urlRequest = request.urlRequest else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var cancelable: AnyPublisher<Data, Error>
        
        if let url = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString,
           let cachedData = cache[url],
           cachedData.isValid {
            cancelable = cacheSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            cacheSubject.send(cachedData.data)
            cacheSubject.send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>.finished)
        } else {
            cancelable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest).tryMap {[weak self] (data, response) -> Data in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw SSNetworkError(httpCode: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0, data: data)
                }
                if request.shouldCacheNow,
                   let url = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString {
                    self?.cache[url] = CachedData(data: data, expirationTime: request.cacheExpirationTime)
                }
                return data
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        if onMainThread {
            return cancelable
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .decode(type: D.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return cancelable
                .decode(type: D.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct CachedData {
    let data: Data
    let expirationTime: Date
    
    var isValid: Bool {
        return Date().compare(expirationTime) != .orderedDescending
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I can notice is that your cancellable property is inside a function which is wrong I guess it should be inside your class otherwise it won't hold any value after function scope.

Comment: The cache code happens synchronously, so you're sending a value before there is a subscriber to receive it. And subjects don't store values - it's basically gone

Comment: @CrackIt, I return it afterward, the caller is responsible to keep the reference to the cancallable

Comment: @NewDev Good catch. Thanks

Comment: @NewDev I tried to call the sends after returning the subscriber but it still only send the completion

Comment: That was just an explanation for what happened. For your case, you shouldn't be using a subject; instead return the publisher that produces there result, and use `flatMap` for logic. Also, you're not using the notation correction: a cancellable is what you get after you use a subscriber like `.sink` or `.assign`. What you have is a publisher (an `AnyPublisher`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the right case to use a subject. Instead, return the publisher, relevant to each case:

```
public class SSNetworkManager {
    // ...
    
    public func makeServiceCall<D: Decodable>(
           forRequest request: SSNetworkRequest<D>, 
           onMainThread: Bool = true
        ) -> AnyPublisher<D, Error>? {

        // consider just returning Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher() instead of nil
        guard let urlRequest = request.urlRequest else {
            return nil
        }

        var resultPublisher: AnyPublisher<D: Error>
        
        if let url = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString,
           let cachedData = cache[url],
           cachedData.isValid {

            resultPublisher = Just(cachedData.data)
                      .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                      .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        } else {
            resultPublisher = URLSession.shared
                .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
                .tryMap { ... }
                .decode(type: D.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        return onMainThread
               ? resultPublisher
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
               : resultPublisher
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NewDev, you've saved me from a headache. didn't know Just exists. And also the async subject send didn't work because I created a mess with the references.